# How do I query with vuefire?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

```
import { collection, limit, query } from "firebase/firestore"
import { useFirestore, useCollection } from "vuefire"

const db = useFirestore()

const messagesRef = collection(db, 'rooms/1/messages')
const messages = useCollection(query(messagesRef, limit(3)))
       
console.log(messages.value)
```

**messages.value** should be an array of 3 elements, instead I get an empty one. However, if I print only messages (**console.log(messages)**) i see the expected values in the value field. I don't know if it's a vuefire bug or something. With firebase api everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's an async operation to retrieve these values, `console.log(messages)` logged to your dev console will actually update itself to show the "live" async result.  [MDN on logging objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects):

> Don't use console.log(obj), use console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))).
>
> This way you are sure you are seeing the value of obj at the moment you log it. Otherwise, many browsers provide a live view that constantly updates as values change. This may not be what you want.

Being an array, `console.log(messages.value)` is going to log immediately before the async operation has had a chance to finish (hence, empty array). To really test it, try `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messages)))`. I think you should get the empty result again.